# How to disable windows snap target

Tags: windows, windows-10

In a fresh install of Windows 10 Pro. When I drag a window a snap target position image is displayed. See image.

[image]

This is very frustrating as the image is often displayed under the place where I want to place the window. The affect being that the window is therefore snapped and not placed where I intended it to be.

How do I disable this?

To be clear I don't want to disable snapping altogether just the annoying destination image underlay

UPDATE

I do not have the option to "Allow the system to suggest companion windows when using Snap"

[image]

Comment: You are running Version 1511 right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by 3rd party software - For Dell Check - Dell PremierColor.

**Windows**

Under Settings > System > Multitasking,

This will allow you to disable the overlay.

[image]

Comment: That option is not present under Settings > Multitasking. See my update

Comment: @DavidGlenn, Please see edit, its cause by Dell PremierColor

Comment: Uninstalling Dell Premier Color removed it.

Answer (score 6):

As @Wessel mentioned this is caused by Dell PremierColor. To disable it, open PremierColor, switch to advanced mode, and disable "Display Splitter".

[image: Display Splitter]